# PHP preg_replace match special characters but not utf8 letters

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I have some titles, for example:

```
should? be fenêtre!

ﻟﻔﺮﻧﺴﻴﺔ-تعاني!!!
```

What regex expression can i use to remove special characters like: ?,!,^

I need to get those titles like this:

```
should-be-fenêtre

ﻟﻔﺮﻧﺴﻴﺔ-تعاني
```

I tried

```
$name = preg_replace("~[\x00-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7F]+~", "-", $name);
```

But i get

```
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '~' found in
```

Thanks

Comment: By "special characters" you actually mean punctuation?

Comment: Yes, all characters like: .,?/*&^%$ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a couple of regular expressions to strip out anything that is not a letter or a number and condense runs of whitespace and dashes to just a single dash:

```
// Replaces every non-letter, non-digit with a dash
$str = preg_replace('/(?=\P{Nd})\P{L}/u', '-', $str);

// Replaces runs of whitespace and dashes with a single dash
$str = preg_replace('/[\s-]{2,}/u', '-', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you say what \P{Nd} and \P{L} do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(?![.=$'€%-])\p{P}/u", "", $text);
```

Just change the assertion to match whatever Unicode characters you want to keep.